# Find Population from Model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

First time I asked this it didn't get entered correctly so got wrong answers, which helped explain a different question I had.

$$\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{2p(7-p)}{700}$$

Given $p(0) = 3$ and $p \gt 0$, find $p(57)$.

I'm able to separate the variables and get

$$\frac{700}{(2p)(7-p)} = dt$$

Integrating giving me.

$$50 (\ln|p| - \ln|7-p|) = t + C$$

I solve for $p(0)=3$ giving me $C = -14.38$

The problem now arises that when I go to solve for $p(57)$ that the $p$'s inside the $\ln$ will cancel when raised exponentiated. Suggestions?

Comment: Not sure I am following. To solve for $p$, disregard the absolute value signs (at least for the moment) and write it as $\frac {p}{7-p}=e^{\frac {t+C}{50}}$  whence $p=\frac {7e^{\frac {t+C}{50}}}{1+e^{\frac {t+C}{50}}}$, with your numbers I get about $4.9075$.  Ignoring the absolute values just means we are looking for solutions $0<p<7$.  If you want solutions in a different range, change the signs accordingly.

Comment: $$50\ln\left(\frac{p(57)}{7-p(57)}\right){}{}{}{}{}=57+50\ln\left(\frac{p(0)}{7-p(0)}\right)$$ hence $$\frac{p(57)}{7-p(57)}=\frac{3}{7-3}e^{57/50}\implies p(57)=\ldots$$